# How to add parameter in state `url` in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add a parameter to my angular application. actually my app will dynamically called as :

```
"https://abc.ss.com/xx/sn=1234568505
```

to handle this `state` - in my `$stateProvider` - I am trying like this:

```
 .state('serialCreateCase', {
        url: '/sn=*', //but not working
        templateUrl:'abxy.html',
        controller: 'controllersss as ctrl',
        }
      })
```

But my URL is not capturing redirecting to default page. how to add the `=` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.state('serialCreateCase', {
  url: '^/sn={id}',
  params: {
    id: {}
  },
  templateUrl:'abxy.html',
  controller: 'controllersss as ctrl',
}
```

That should match the url you're expecting.

Edit: answer has been updated to change it to required parameters.

Comment: But even without the `id` it works, `http://localhost:3000/sn=` - is valid now. But I would like to required the id compulsory

Comment: As well the `id` should be without special characters.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include required parameter value.

Comment: But now the `id` always requires the number. how can i make this accept both mixing of `alphabets` and numbers? `abc1234 or 1233ccm` - like so?

Comment: You can change it slightly to '^/sn={id}' that will not require it to be an integer (answer edited to reflect this)

Comment: I am still getting some issue. I just want to exactly match this: `sn=1234568505` - else let it go for default, at present still `sn=` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this: http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters

Query Parameters

So that query parameters are mapped to UI Router's $stateParams object, you need to declare them in your state configuration's URL template:

```
state('new-qs', {
  url: '/new?portfolioId',
  templateUrl: 'new.html',
  controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
     $scope.portfolioId = $stateParams.portfolioId;
  }
})
```

You can then create a link to this state using the ui-sref attribute:

```
<a ui-sref="new-qs({ portfolioId: 1 })">New (query string)</a>
```

This will navigate to /new?portfolioId=1.

If you have multiple optional parameters, separate them with an &:

```
state('new-qs', {
  url: '/new?portfolioId&param1&param2',
  templateUrl: 'new.html',
  controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
     $scope.portfolioId = $stateParams.portfolioId;
     $scope.param1 = $stateParams.param1;
     $scope.param2 = $stateParams.param2;
  }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

You could add params like this

```
state('serialCreateCase', {
 url: '/xx?sn',
 templateUrl: 'abxy.html',
 controller: 'controllersss as ctrl',
 }
})
```

The state ref will be

```
<a ui-sref="serialCreateCase({ sn: 1234568505 })">URL</a>
```

Comment: For example in my localhost : `localhost:3000/sn=12345` - need to handled. but I tried yours, still it takes me to default page